# Why must $r$ equal $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Professor Munkres begins a proof of matrices having inverses only if their number of rows is equal to their number of columns is equal to their rank by

> Let $A$ be a $k$ by $n$ matrix. First, suppose $B$ is a right inverse for $A$. Then $A\cdotp B=I_k$. It follows that the system of equations $A\cdotp X = C$ has a solution for arbitrary $C$, for the vector $X=B \cdotp C$ is one such solution. Theorem 6 then implies that $r$ must equal $k$.

Now Theorem 6 states that

> If $r<k$, then there exist vectors $C$ in $V_k$ such that the system $A\cdotp X = C$ has no solution.
> If $r=k$, then the system $A\cdotp X=C$ always has a solution.

Hence I don't understand why he states that about Theorem 6, given that Theorem 6 states that there may be a solution for $r<k$ as long as the vectors $C$ correspond (They must have some elements = $0$).

Comment: I think the reasoning is pretty easy to get. If $r < k$, then Thm. 6 states that we could could find *some* $C$ s.t. $AX=C$ has no solutions, while for this invertible $A$, we already knew that $AX = C$ has a solution for *any* $C$, contradiction.

Comment: @xbh Yup. Thanks.... I don't know what I was thinking!